# Get value from a field in another content

Tags: entities

I have two content types : content_type_1 and content_type_2.

I'm trying to call a value from content_type_1 in content_type_2 according to an entity reference field in content_type_2 which point to the nid of content_type_1.

I tried to do it with a computed field with the above code :

```
$entity_field[0]['value'] = "db_result(db_query("SELECT field_CONTENT_TYPE_1_value FROM content_type_CONTENT_TYPE_1 WHERE nid=%d",$node->field_CONTENT_TYPE_2[0][nid]))"
```

- field_CONTENT_TYPE_1 is the field I want the value from
- content_type_CONTENT_TYPE_1 is the content type of field_CONTENT_TYPE_1
- field_CONTENT_TYPE_2 is the entity reference field which point to nid.

I have to say I'm absolutely not a php dev, so I'm just playing with php snippets I found around.

What's the way to achieve this with computed field ?

Comment: Why not `entity_load("node", <id>)` the get the other node and then get the field value from the loaded object?

Comment: Because I need to write it again in the database to call it with views after. And actually I would like to store a geofield field to use proximity filter then. Is it possible with entity_load ?

Comment: Use `entity_save()` to save the entity back to the database?

Comment: So I will have to make a custom module ?